# Heroku Error while Google sign in with passport-google-oauth20

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, google-signin, passport-google-oauth2

I am using passport-google-oauth20 GoogleStrategy in express js for user login. Website hosting on Heroku. When I try to login then all user details goes into mongodb database but screen stuck in Heroku error " Application error" page. After this when i put in my website's Home page's url directly then I find I am logged in. After that everything works fine. Now main problem is "why screen stuck in Heroku's 'Application Error' page after pressing google sign in button?"
when I check Heroku logs then I found app getting path with "http" protocol instead "https" which is already updated on Google developer console Authorized redirect URIs.
please give your views if you understand the problem.
Than you.
Code is here for more clerity :-

config/passport.js

```
    const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy
const FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

const User = require('../models/User')

module.exports = function (passport) {
  passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
      {
        clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
      },
      async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        console.log(profile)
        console.log(passport.session._id)
        const newUser = {
          Id: profile.id,
          provider: profile.provider,
          displayName: profile.displayName,
          firstName: profile.name.givenName,
          lastName: profile.name.familyName,
          image: profile.photos[0].value,
          email: profile.emails[0].value,
        }
        try {
          let user = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id })

          if (user) {
            done(null, user)
          } else {
            user = await User.create(newUser)
            done(null, user)
            if (user) {
              done(null, user)
            }
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.error('==========', err)
        }
      }
    )
  )
```

routes/auth.js

```
const express = require('express')
const passport = require('passport')
const router = express.Router()

//google
router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['email','profile'] }))
router.get('/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google', {successRedirect: '/',failureRedirect: '/auth/login' }));
```

//root directory
index.js

```
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const methodOverride = require('method-override')
const passport = require('passport')
const Session = require('express-session')
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')
const connectDB = require('./config/db')
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const app = express()
const log = function (request, response, next) {
  console.log(`${new Date()}: ${request.protocol}://${request.get('host')}${request.originalUrl}`);
  console.log(request.body); // make sure JSON middleware is loaded before this line
  next();
}
global.loggedIn = '';

dotenv.config({ path: './config/config.env' })
require('./config/passport')(passport)
connectDB()
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(
  methodOverride('_method', function (req, res) {
    if (req.body && typeof req.body === 'object' && '_method' in req.body) {
      let method = req.body._method
      delete req.body._method
      return method
    }
  })
)
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({ defaultLayout: 'main' }));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
try {
  app.use(
    Session({
      secret: 'keyboard cat',
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      store: MongoStore.create({
        mongoUrl: process.env.MONGO_URI
      })
    })
  )
  console.log("Sessions successfully initialized!");
} catch (err) {
  console.log(`Error setting up a mongo session store! `);
}

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

app.use(fileUpload())
app.use(flash());
app.use(log);

// Set global var
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('express session', req.session)
  console.log('passport session', req.user)
  res.locals.user = req.user || null
  loggedIn = res.locals.user
  next()
})
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

app.use('/', require('./routes/index'));
app.use('/auth', require('./routes/auth'));
app.use('/', require('./routes/reviews'));
app.use('/', require('./routes/comments'));
app.use((req, res) => res.render('notfound.ejs'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000
app.listen(
  PORT,
  console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`)
)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thankyou anyway, problem has been solved... I took everything in index.js then started working fine and then again create a root. its ok now.